# Intercept ScrollView zoom before it bounces back

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit

I want to receive a callback when a ScrollView's zooming view is scaled below a threshold so that I can dismiss the view controller.  I'm currently using the `bouncesZoom` property which allows the zooming view to be scaled below the `minimumZoomScale` and snap back when the user ends the gesture.

I considered using `scrollViewDidEndZooming` with passes me a `scale` parameter.  The problem is that this callback is triggered *after* the zooming view bounces back to `minimumZoomScale`.  Therefore, the dismissal transition would include the bounce back and that isn't the desired effect.

I considered setting the `bouncesZoom` to `NO` when the `zoomScale` dips below the threshold.  But that has the effect of snapping the zooming view instantly to the `minimumZoomScale`.

I also tried setting the `minimumZoomScale` to the current `zoomScale` once it dips below the threshold.  This solves the bounce back problem because the `zoomScale` is now equal to the `minimumZoomScale` and so the bounce back is imperceptible.  This has a visual glitch as well when I make that assignment.  I'm not sure it is safe to set the `minimumZoomScale` to the current `zoomScale` while zooming.  So this approach isn't ideal either.

What can I do to hook into the gesture end event and avoid the bounce back?